# how to load content in a dynamic created div with ajax on a click

Tags: javascript, jquery

This my current code:

```
var container, url;

$(".nav-list li a").on("click", function(e) {

   e.preventDefault();

   var $url = this.href + " #content";
   var container = $("#content");

   $(".nav li").removeClass("active");
   $(this).parent().addClass("active");

   $(this).addClass("clicked");

   var $row = $(".span10");
   var $rowNew = $('.new');

   if ($rowNew.children().length > 1) {
        $(".span10 div").removeClass("new");
        $('<div class="row-fluid new"></div>').prependTo($row);
   }

   if ($(".new").length == 0) {
        $('<div class="row-fluid new"></div>').prependTo($row);
        $('<div class="span6">' + container.load(url) + '</div>').appendTo('.new');
   } else {
        $('<div class="span6">' + container.load(url) + '</div>').appendTo('.new');
   }

});
```

I am trying to load content inside `<div class="span6">`HERE`</div>` but I am getting confused on how to set the .load and load the content in it.

Current html output:

```
<div class="row-fluid new">
   <div class="span6">
       container.load(url)
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess the row `var url = this.href + ".content";` wont work as `this.href` in the jquery context should be `$(this).attr('href')`

Comment: WHy you have `var container, url;` and than again `var url = this.href + ".content";
   var container = $("#content");`

Comment: Have you tried loading first, and then use container.html()?

Comment: @roXon var container, url; was a typo, thanks

Comment: @jtheman changed $(this) and updated the question with th current output

Comment: Whats the purpose of `$('#content').removeAttr('id');`?

Comment: @jtheman you are right, my apologies, deleted that line now

Comment: updated the question with the current html output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think you should use `load` this way; it is only meant to place the result into an existing element that you know beforehand. Better use `get` with a success callback:

```
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).attr('href') + ".content";

    [...]

    $.get(url, '', function(result) {
      if ($(".new").length == 0) {
        $('<div class="row-fluid new"></div>').prependTo($row);
        $('<div class="span6">' + result+ '</div>').appendTo('.new');
      } else {
        $('<div class="span6">' + result + '</div>').appendTo('.new');
      }
    });
```

No need to use the  `var container = $("#content");` and remove its id in the process.

Comment: Nothing is load, not even adding the new divs

Comment: this is what i did and i get nothing at all, not even new divs http://pastebin.com/27DCXS8n

Comment: Ah, I see that `url` is undefined. If you want to use the href of the currently clicked link, use `var url = $(this).attr('href');` instead of the current `var $url = ...` (just `var url =  this.href` might usually work, too)

Comment: yes i changed it to var url = this.href + ".content"; but it doesn't load the content, what it does is it replaces the whole thing. I don't see the new divs created

Comment: I get an error in the inspector that refers to another part of the code, but it is fine. SO it has to do with this bit here

Comment: Hm, it somewhat works here. Can you see in the inspector if the Ajax call is fired at all? If that is not succesfull, nothing is added. If in doubt, a temporary `$(this).load(url)` to load the stuff into the current link, just for debugging and to see if the results arrive, might help.

Comment: Forget it, I had to run jQuery(function($){ as i had some conflits with using $. Accepted your anwwer. Thanks a lot

Comment: ah, phew, thanks, curiously I had a similar problem with the $ just a few hours ago ;)